# is there there a way to run AS/400 commands on a batch file

Tags: batch-file, ftp, ibm-midrange

I am trying to create a virtual device and image catalog to upload files into an ifs o the AS/400. I have tried several variations and trials and can not figure this out. My batch file does all I need to a point, but at the time of the virtual devices, it doesn't know the commands. These are AS/400 commands that I don't know if/how to get them to run in FTP.
Perhaps my only choice is to create a macro on the AS-400, but I would rather not. Any suggestions?

```
@echo off

SET /P release= Please enter in release number: 

if EXIST ftpcmd2.dat goto :justRunIt

SET /P userpw= Please enter in AHC password: 
SET /P IPaddr= Please enter in IP address of the AS400: 

 >ftpcmd2.dat echo.quote LODIMGCLG IMGCLG(AHCUPD) OPTION(*UNLOAD)
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.quote RMVIMGCLGE IMGCLG(AHCUPD) IMGCLGIDX(1) KEEP(*NO)
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.open %IPaddr%
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.user
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.ahc
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.%userpw%
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.cd /
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.mkdir Global
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.cd Global
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.mkdir %release%
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.cd %release%
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.bin
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.lcd c:\ahc
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.put Update%release%.iso
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.CRTDEVOPT DEVD(OPTvrt03) RSRCNAME(*VRT) TEXT('Virtual CD/DVD Device')
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.quote VRYCFG CFGOBJ(OPTVRT03) CFGTYPE(*DEV) STATUS(*ON) RANGE(*OBJ)
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.quote CRTIMGCLG IMGCLG(AHCUPD) DIR('/UPDATE') CRTDIR(*YES) TEXT('Image catalog for AHC Updates')
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.quote ADDIMGCLGE (IMGCLG(AHCUPD) FROMFILE('/gLOBAL/%RELEASE%/uPDATE%RELEASE%.iso')
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.quote LODIMGCLG IMGCLG(AHCUPD) DEV(OPTVRT03) OPTION(*LOAD)
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.quote LODRUN DEV(OPT03)

:justRunIt
ftp -n -s:ftpcmd2.dat
```

Comment: ftp can only run ftp commands.  Period.  If you need to run other commands you need to submit it as a job to run.  I don't know how the AS/400 works but I use z/os and I just submit a JCL to JES2 to run programs.

Comment: Because commands such as CRTDEVOPT require *IOSYSCFG special authority, they should **not be run** through FTP. In general, user profiles with any 'special authority' should not be logging on at all through FTP -- significant security issue.

Comment: Best here to create a CL program that creates the virtual device and tape. That CL Program can carry authorities necessary to do configuration. Then the user logging on to FTP does not need special authority, just `*USE` authority to the program.

Comment: You might upload and run a REXX script.

Answer (score 2):

[rcmd](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzaiq/rzaiqrcmd.htm) is an FTP command used from the client that sends an OS command to the FTP server.  Usually used with the quote command.

So you'd want:

```
>>ftpcmd2.dat echo.quote rcmd CRTDEVOPT DEVD(OPTvrt03) RSRCNAME(*VRT) TEXT('Virtual CD/DVD Device')
```

However, creating the virtual optical device and the image catalog every time is quite unusual. They are usually created once and reused.